# How to install python2.6 in alpine container?

Tags: python, gcc, docker, alpine-linux

How to install python2.6 in alpine docker container.

I tried to install from source, its giving me compilation errors.

Actually I want to install Python2.6 and Python2.7 in container. So that I can run  unittests on  both Python2.6 and Python2.7. Please give some thoughts on this.

I have installed gcc , g++ , make in alpine container then did the following steps.

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6/Python-2.6.tgz
tar xvzf Python-2.6.tgz
cd Python-2.6
./configure
make
```

Got this error while make,

```
~/Python-2.6 # make
gcc -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/config.o Modules/config.c
gcc -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -DPYTHONPATH='":plat-linux4:lib-tk:lib-old"' \
    -DPREFIX='"/usr/local"' \
    -DEXEC_PREFIX='"/usr/local"' \
    -DVERSION='"2.6"' \
    -DVPATH='""' \
    -o Modules/getpath.o ./Modules/getpath.c
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/posixmodule.c -o Modules/posixmodule.o
./Modules/posixmodule.c:6173:1: error: conflicting types for 'posix_close'
 posix_close(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
 ^
In file included from Include/Python.h:44:0,
                 from ./Modules/posixmodule.c:30:
/usr/include/unistd.h:38:5: note: previous declaration of 'posix_close' was here
 int posix_close(int, int);
     ^
Makefile:1234: recipe for target 'Modules/posixmodule.o' failed
make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1
```

Can any one suggest how can I solve this ?

Comment: Not sure it will help, but maybe it would be worth a moment to take a look how Alpine used to build 2.6: http://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/python?id=96e95a93287adc9c6bdf8689fa974b11d41dc492 and how they build 2.7: http://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/python2.

Answer (score 1):

Docker has a [official repos](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/), which are pretty convenient to use. Conveniently, there is a [python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) official repo. It has images for different version of Python (including 2.7) and different base OSes (including alpine). I would recommend using the official *2.7-alphine* image and using [its Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/693a75332e8ae5ad3bfae6e8399c4d7cc3cb6181/2.7/alpine/Dockerfile) as a reference for installing python 2.6.

I would also recommend having separate images, one with python 2.6 and one with 2.7 rather than having both in the same image. This would help avoid having to install/configure two different versions of python side by side.

---

It's hard to tell why your build didn't work without seeing the rest of your Dockerfile, but one place to start is build dependencies. The official Dockerfile adds build dependencies on lines [37-53](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/693a75332e8ae5ad3bfae6e8399c4d7cc3cb6181/2.7/alpine/Dockerfile#L37-L53), that list has more dependencies than the ones you said you installed.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by tweaking the patch from this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue20594 to Python 2:

```
--- ./Modules/posixmodule.c.orig
+++ ./Modules/posixmodule.c
@@ -3896,7 +3896,7 @@
 #endif
     gid_t grouplist[MAX_GROUPS];

-    /* On MacOSX getgroups(2) can return more than MAX_GROUPS results
+    /* On MacOSX getgroups(2) can return more than MAX_GROUPS results
      * This is a helper variable to store the intermediate result when
      * that happens.
      *
@@ -6357,7 +6357,7 @@
 Close a file descriptor (for low level IO).");

 static PyObject *
-posix_close(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
+posix_closex(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
 {
     int fd, res;
     if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i:close", &fd))
@@ -8602,7 +8602,7 @@
     {"tcsetpgrp",       posix_tcsetpgrp, METH_VARARGS, posix_tcsetpgrp__doc__},
 #endif /* HAVE_TCSETPGRP */
     {"open",            posix_open, METH_VARARGS, posix_open__doc__},
-    {"close",           posix_close, METH_VARARGS, posix_close__doc__},
+    {"close",           posix_closex, METH_VARARGS, posix_close__doc__},
     {"closerange",      posix_closerange, METH_VARARGS, posix_closerange__doc__},
     {"dup",             posix_dup, METH_VARARGS, posix_dup__doc__},
     {"dup2",            posix_dup2, METH_VARARGS, posix_dup2__doc__},
```

I posted my full Dockerfile and patch here:

https://gist.github.com/cwill747/722f41d8807c3b41a1e417849634cfe5

Answer (score 0):

For python2.7, you could use [frolvlad/alpine-python2](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-python2), which is a 50MB python2.7 image based on alpine.

And for python2.6, you could get the Dockerfile and update it, so that it works for that version as well